# Critique: Typography for my website

Tags: website-design, fonts, typography, critique

Here is a picture of my website (and also [the link](http://dev.be-pixel.com/db-alt/)) as it is now (still under construction). I've tried various combinations in term of font size, font weight, etc. but can't find "the right" balance so external advice would be much appreciated (especially for the top part: header, menu, sub-header). What would you change?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some notes on possible improvements:

1. The page uses eight different typefaces, *and* variation in font size *and* different content color and background color combinations. That makes a rather messy impression. Using two or three typefaces should normally be enough.
2. Legibility is suboptimal. White text on dark background is less legile, and white text on light background is an even bigger problem. The menu would probably work better when semi-bold Open Sans is used, perhaps in a little larger size.
3. Text column width (line length) is over 80 characters. The common typographic recommendation is about 60 characters, or less, for readability.
4. Copy text has large gaps between words. Text justified on both sides easily causes such problems, unless word division is enabled (can be done with Hyphenator.js).

Comment: +1. seconded! _eight_ typefaces! Keep in mind that a fontface in different sizes can _also_ visually be registered as "different" and adds to messyness.